# How do I set the window size of VideoCapture?

Tags: python, opencv

In the following snippet of code how would I set the size of the capture window? I want to take a 256*256 pixel picture.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
  ret, frame = cap.read()
  cv2.imshow('img1',frame) 
  if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('y'): 
     cv2.imwrite('imag.png',frame)
     cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the size of the window like so

```
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
video_capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 256)
video_capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 256)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can alternatively use OpenCVs `resize` function or slice your frame if you are just interested in a certain region of your captured image.